# How can I programmatically determine if VS2012 Update 1 is installed?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012

For our build system I want to be able to make sure only VS2012 Update 1 is used and *not* basic VS2012. How can I do this programatically?

Normally, I'd check that the correct Service Pack is installed. But this is an *update*, not a Service Pack. So all the registry entries for Service Packs still say zero.

Ah, I have investigated further...

In all cases, we check the version of the compiler matches what we expect. I was led astray because the amd64 version of cl.exe reports the *same* version as pre-Update 1 (17.00.50727.1) so I was looking for some other way to do the detection. On the other hand, the x86, x86_amd64, and x86_arm versions of cl.exe all report a new version (17.00.51106.1).

A couple of people have already asked for clarification of whether this is intended in the comments to the [MS blog post about the update](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/11/26/visual-studio-2012-update-1-now-available.aspx) without any response.

I suppose I could check the version in crtversion.h, but am now worried that the amd64 compiler has not been updated to work correctly with the new CRT.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a registry key that changes between *VS2012* and *VS2012 Update 1* I recommend you check in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\SplashInfo`

In Visual Studio 2012 there isn't a `EnvVersion` key.

In Visual Studio 2012 Update 1 it exists with the following value:
EnvVersion = `11.0.51106.01 Update 1`